# What is the reason behind the stored procedures performance degradation in a data-full DB (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

Testing the stored procedures and the modules that interacts with it performance I noticed that the performance of the stored procedure is degenerating as the tables become full. Can anyone explain the reasons behind this from a theoretical perspective. In particular:

1. Is this related to insertion speed as the B-tree index is getting bigger?
2. Is it related to table size? If (no/yes) - why?
3. Is it related to index tree rebalancing somehow (how does MS SQL maintain it's indexes)?
4. can it be related to indexes structure (for example I have clustered indexes on primary keys of both tables that the stored procedure writes data to)?
5. Any other considerations? How should I approach this problem, what is the thinking process?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Could you provide few more details? What do you mean by "table becomes full"? There is some limitation on table/database size but i really doubt you will ever face it. What exactly your procedures do? Is this OLTP environment with many parallel relatively small transactions or you perform some huge data processing job or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries become slower as data size increases for a couple of reasons.  A big reason is the need for useful indexes along with query tuning.  When more data than necessary is touched by queries, unproductive work increases proportionally to table sizes.  Another is disk I/O.  Once needed data is too large to all fit into memory, disk I/O will more often be required to retrieve needed data, which is many orders of magnitude slower than in-memory access.

Slowness for the above reasons can quickly cascade into other issues, such as blocking and deadlocking.  Again, the key to performance regardless of table size is attention to detail in query and index tuning.  Examine the execution plans of frequently executed and/or problem stored procedures for improvement opportunities.  Incremental keys can help keep most recently inserted data in memory and reduce index maintenance costs.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but you are talking about degradation of READ speeds on big tables. I'm asking is there a reason why the inserts should become slower as the table record size increases from say 1 mln to 4 mln? Thanks :)

Comment: Slower inserts as table size grows often indicates a non-incremental key value, especially with the clustered index.  See https://www.dbdelta.com/improving-uniqueidentifier-performance/ for examples of how this can affect performance.

Comment: Could there be any other reasons? May you recommend any additional resources that succinctly explain what happens upon insert to the data, indexes, partitions and such? Thanks :)

Comment: Keep in mind that an insert is basically a read followed by a rewrite.  Performance should be linear regardless of table size as long as the needed pages are in memory.  Are your clustered index keys incremental?

Comment: Two questions: (i) Could you explain the sentence "a read followed by a rewrite" - i think not "data-read" - what kind of read then? Is this read necessary to find the last occurrence of the data? And (ii) why rewrite - what is it rewriting? You mean random data on the disk in an empty location?

Comment: SQL Server operates on data in memory, not directly on disk.  A insert of a row must first traverse the CI b-tree from top to bottom to find the appropriate data page for the new key.  During this traversal, pages are read from disk only if not already in memory.  The target data page is then updated in memory.  Even when a new empty page is needed, it is still an in-memory operation of one read from disk.  The physical disk page rewrites occur asynchronously by the lazy writer and checkpoint processes.